# GET an object from mongodb using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

The problem is probably simple, but my 2 AM brain can't understand what's going on anymore. I'm trying to create a profile page that shows basic public info. The way I'm trying to make it work is pulling out the users username from mongodb when registered the account by his specific _id. If needed, verification I use is JWT.

```
app.post('/api/user-profile', async (req,res) => {
  const { token } = req.body

  if(!token) {
      return res.json({ status: 'error', error: 'not logged in' })
  }

  try {
      const user = jwt.verify(token, JWT_SECRET)
      const userid = user.id
   
      const result = User.findOne({ userid })

      console.log(result)
      // return res.json({ status: 'ok', name: result })
  } catch(error) {
      // return res.json({ status: 'error', error: 'something went wrong' })
      console.log(error)
  }
})
```

I'm not sure what function should I use, `findOne()` or `findById()`. I tried to look at the documentation at mongoose, but the explanation is a bit too hard for me to understand.

P.S User = the user registration model. If needed I can paste in the code.

Comment: if your problem is not solved leave a comment,  If my answers has solved your question, please accept it, so both of us gain more reputation and other users can see that this answer solved your problem. See this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `findById` instead of `findOne` if `userid` is `_id` and use `await` before the query, so do like this:

```
const result = await User.findById(userid)
```

if you want to use findOne :

```
const result = await User.findOne({"_id" : userid})
```

if you want a plain object javascript use `.toObject` after query like this:

```
const result = await User.findById(userid).toObject()
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a lot of experience with mongoose but worked with Mongo quite a lot. findOne is a direct correspondent of Mongo's findOne function which receives a query in the format {"key": "expectedValue"}. If you want to use it to get data by id the query is {"_id": user.id}.

Because fetching data by id is a common case, the lib added the method findByID which receives an ID, and then formats the query and makes an internal call to findOne.

Comment: I's there a way I can get the output like exactly what the username is instead of getting a massive output including the model name and everything. I've tried this: 

const user = jwt.verify(token, JWT_SECRET)
        
const result = User.findOne({ "_id": user.username })

console.log(result)

Comment: If I correctly understand and your usecase is readonly you can use lean method: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-lean

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, the answer is just like Mohammad Yaser Ahmadi said. Everything works fine, and by getting the username I did:

```
const user = jwt.verify(token, JWT_SECRET)
const userid = user.id

const result = await User.findById(userid)

const usersName = result.username

console.log(usersName)
```